# Understanding AWS API Gateway with HTTP Proxy

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am new in API gateways. I have python based API deployed on an EC2 server. I can access this as URL http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/. I can see objects, methods in this URL. I am trying to use API gateway for same.

1. Created API. (ExampleAPI)
2. Created POST method. (given path http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/ as end point URL ). I have not created the resource since I am expecting HTTP Proxy for all Methods of the resource. Its looks fine when I put my content in the request body. I get a response.
3. Now I have deployed it to one stage dev1. Got a new endpoint URL.
4. Also created an API key and attached it with dev1. Also Set API key required true in POST Method Request.

Questions.
1. When I hit dev1 URL (https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1), it does not give me same page as http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/. It gives me {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error. Am I missing some fundamentals here?

2. http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/ do have several methods, so how can I use it? All of them are POST methods. Can I set some parameters or some request body, or some templates? How can I improve this process?
3. How can I use API key here? Or it won`t work in POST method?
4. If i do curl -H "Content-Type: application/JSON" -X POST -d "{\"method\": \"app.menu\",\"params\":[] }" https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1 i get same response as i curl http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/. is it the only way to access my dev1 URL or I can create individual methods or string parameters.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: I replied on the forum post, please check that out https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=734000&#734000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answers posted to [this forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=734000&#734000):

> > 1. When i hit dev1 URL (https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1), it do not give
> >        me same page as http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/. It gives me
> >        {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"} error. Am i missing some
> >        fundamentals here ?
>
> If you are hitting the URL in a browser with a GET method, it will not
>   work. You have to specify all of the HTTP methods on a resource that
>   you want the client to access. If you hit a method that is not
>   defined, you get that message.
>
> > 2. http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/ do have several methods, so how can i use it? all of them are POST methods. Can i set some parameters or
> >        some request body, or some templates. how can i improve this process.
>
> Yes if you are mapping to an RPC API then you can build the REST
>   methods/resources in API Gateway and set a static value for the header
>   or in the body, wherever the RPC action is expected by the backend.
>
> > 3. How can i use API key here? or it won`t work in POST method? Because while accessing from curl, it works fine without API key.
>
> First you should set API Key Required on the method (Method Request
>   page), then you'll have to add the API Stage to the API Key and make
>   sure it's enabled. After all that, if you send the API Key in a header
>   called 'x-api-key' it should work, otherwise you should get a 403
>   response saying "Forbidden".
>
> > 4. If i do "curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"method\": \"app.menu\",\"params\":[] }"
> >        https://xxxxxxxxxxx-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev1" i get same
> >        response as i curl http://xxx.xxxxxxx.com/RPC2/. is it the only way to
> >        access my dev1 URL or i can create individual methods or string
> >        parametrs.
>
> You will have to create each method in API Gateway (like GET) and they
>   can all point to the same backend url but specify a different RPC
>   action in the header or wherever it is specified.
>
> I'd encourage you to check the public developer guides for parameter
>   mapping and payload transformation to learn what tools we have in API
>   Gateway.